# What percent of functions on OS X are called by the Objective-C runtime?

Tags: ios, macos, runtime, objective-c-runtime, code-statistics

I'd like to get a firmer grasp of how frequently the runtime in any language that requires one is being called. In this case, I'm specifically interested in knowing:

Of all the function calls getting executed on an OS X or iOS system in any given second (approximations are of course necessary) how many of those are Objective-C runtime functions (i.e. functions that are defined by the runtime)?

Comment: Even with approximations, this depends so much on what you're doing that the variation can easily be a few orders of magnitude. I'm not sure what the value of this information is.

Answer (score 2):

Of course it depends on your application, but in general the answer is "a whole lot".  Like, a whole freaking lot.

If you really want to see numbers, I'd recommend using dtrace to log all runtime functions as they're called.  [This blog entry](http://kdbdallas.com/2009/02/07/log-all-accessed-methods-in-objective-c-with-dtrace/) talks about how to do such a thing.

Answer (score 1):

A lot. Here are just a few examples.

Every time you send a message, the actual message sending is done by a runtime function (this is in fact the most called runtime function in pretty much any objective C program).

`NSObject` class and protocol are not part of the standard library but part of the runtime, therefore any method that ends up executing to the default `NSObject` implementation is in fact executing runtime code.

Every time you execute a default property accessor (either read or write), that's part of the runtime.

If you use ARC, every time you access a weak reference (either for reading or writing it) that's a runtime function.

Objc runtime includes the C runtime, so anything that involves a C runtime function (for example passing a large structure by value or returning it) is in fact calling into the runtime.

and more.